# When I update android native contact, I got “java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:”

Tags: android, contacts

When I update android native contact, I got the exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Your selection contains data that can be deleted by ContactsProviderinternals only.
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:168)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithOperationApplicationExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:159)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.applyBatch(ContentProviderNative.java:456)
    at android.content.ContentProviderClient.applyBatch(ContentProviderClient.java:120)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.applyBatch(ContentResolver.java:767)
    at
```

please help me.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, you have first added permissions `android.permission.READ_CONTACTS` and `android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS` then you should post some code, because don't know how you updating them. But you should do it similar like this

```
ContentValues data = new ContentValues();
data.put(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,<data>);
data.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,<data>);
getContentResolver().update(workUri, data, null, null);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
1. I added permissions android.permission.READ_CONTACTS and android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS. 

2. This exception only happened on several customer, but not all.